# In intellij, How to see SVN log/history of a file renamed or moved before previous commit

Tags: java, svn, intellij-idea

In intellij, my project is under SVN control, I have renamed and moved a file then I commited it.
How can I show log/history of this file after this commit with intellij.

Answer (score 0):

"renames and moves are done as a delete followed by an add" via http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html
so this file lost its previous history.

If you know where this file was previously, right click on the directory which contains this file and in SVN context menu find something like 'show history'. It will show you all changes made in this directory, so you can find this specific file.

Answer (score 0):

I find it. As the source file was rename, the subversion history will not show revisions with the old name.

To see old revisions before and after rename the file in intellij, right click subversion> compare with...

You can then compare the correct revision, with revision before rename the file.